# Why does forwarding the name of a function to cout return 1?

Tags: c++

In C++, when you write this inside of main

```
cout << main << endl;
```

the output is

```
1
```

Can anyone explain why this is? It does it for any function created from my experience, but since main is the default function in most programs, that is the one I used in my example.

Comment: The only suitiable overload of `operator<<` is the one taking `bool`. That's the one being called. `1` just means "non-NULL pointer" here.

Comment: It's possible to write your own overload, that's what makes `std::endl` work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik if you could expand on that it would make a great answer.